# Javascript string contains "&nbsp" cannot match

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text in HTML that must include `&nbsp` inside the text, and then I use Javascript to get the `innerHTML` and do comparison, but it doesn't work.

```
   var x = randomGen();
   document.getElementById("c"+x[0]).innerHTML="&nbsp&nbspa, b, c&nbsp&nbsp";
   document.getElementById("c"+x[1]).innerHTML="&nbsp&nbspc, d, e&nbsp&nbsp";
   document.getElementById("c"+x[2]).innerHTML="&nbsp&nbspf, g, h&nbsp&nbsp";
   document.getElementById("c"+x[3]).innerHTML="&nbsp&nbspa, a, a&nbsp&nbsp";

function checkans(ans){
    if (ans=="&nbsp&nbspa, a, a&nbsp&nbsp") {
       alert(ans);
    }
}
```

HTML body:

```
<div class="ans" id="c1" onclick="checkans(this.innerText)"></div>
<div class="ans" id="c2" onclick="checkans(this.innerText)"></div>
<div class="ans" id="c3" onclick="checkans(this.innerText)"></div>
<div class="ans" id="c4" onclick="checkans(this.innerText)"></div>
```

All cases return false.

Comment: Do you actually mean the _text_ `&nbsp` - or the HTML entity for the non-breaking space character? The latter needs a trailing semicolon of course.

Comment: @CBroe means HTML entities are like this: `&nbsp;`

Comment: I want to know why it doesn't reach the condition, when I click the correct answer.

Comment: Why don't you have semicolons after your `&nbsp`s? Like this: `&nbsp;`

Comment: @OldBunny2800 why would `ans` need to be defined? It's being passed in the function call...

Comment: I can do it when I replace `&nbsp` with `" "`, but I must use `&nbsp` . So I have to do the comparison using `&nbsp`.

Comment: `&nbsp` is _wrong_, the HTML entity is written `&nbsp;`

Comment: Oh, @NewToJS never mind about the definition, I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: This is rather the wrong way to go about this anyway. You are making the logic of the script depend on what is basically _formatting_. This seems to be some kind of quiz(?), so you should rather put the value that you actually need to check into a _custom data attribute_ on those elements, and then compare that, instead of the innerHTML content.

Comment: No it is not a quiz, but if I don't use `&nbsp;`, space is not added in the text.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking as your code is chock-full of what appear to be typos. You either need to *clarify* what you are trying to do here, or this will almost certainly be closed.

Comment: I mean space cannot be added at the front of text and the end of the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and then I use Javascript to get the innerHTML and do the comparison

This is not true. You're very clearly using `innerText`, not `innerHTML`, and these are not the same things.

If you actually use `innerHTML`, and correct your code to use `&nbsp;` (the browser automatically changes your `&nsbp`s to `&nsbp;` when you assign them to `.innerHTML`), the code works:

```js
var x = [3, 2, 1, 4]
document.getElementById("c" + x[0]).innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;a, b, c&nbsp;&nbsp;";
document.getElementById("c" + x[1]).innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;c, d, e&nbsp;&nbsp;";
document.getElementById("c" + x[2]).innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;f, g, h&nbsp;&nbsp;";
document.getElementById("c" + x[3]).innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;a, a, a&nbsp;&nbsp;";

function checkans(ans) {
  if (ans == "&nbsp;&nbsp;a, a, a&nbsp;&nbsp;") {
    alert(ans);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Click the "a, a, a" option to see an alert box</div>
<div class="ans" id="c1" onclick="checkans(this.innerHTML)"></div>
<div class="ans" id="c2" onclick="checkans(this.innerHTML)"></div>
<div class="ans" id="c3" onclick="checkans(this.innerHTML)"></div>
<div class="ans" id="c4" onclick="checkans(this.innerHTML)"></div>
```